# Rewriting a basic program in so that it uses arguments and parameters in place of global variables

Tags: c++, parameters, arguments, global-variables, parameter-passing

I rearranged it so that it fits the requirement however when I run the code it returns a "undefined reference to 'Power (int, int, int)'.  I boiled it down to a single line but I do not know how to resolve it.  Comparing it to the similar examples I've done it appears to be in order.  I believe the problem is that it is not passing the 'return' back to the main.

```
#include <iostream>

int Power( /* in */ int pow, /* in */ int x, /* out */ int &result);    //prototype

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int pow;
    int x;
    int result;

    cout << "Enter power: ";    //prompt for integer in for power to be raised by
    cin >> pow;                 //integer in
    cout << "Enter value to be raised to power: ";      //prompt for integer to be raised
    cin >> x;                   //integer in
    cout << Power(pow, x, result);      /*function results output.  returns input of Power function***
                                           This line is the problem but why...
                                           If I remove "(pow,x,result)" it will compile but it does not calculate properly.
                                           If I take the while loop from the Power function by itself it calculates fine.
                                           If I replace Power ((pow,x,result) with 'result' it makes a really big number...
                                         */

    return 0;                   //return
}

int Power( /*in */ int pow, /*in */ int x, /*out */ int result);        //Power function     should calculate the result of raising 'x' to the 'pow' entered...
{
    result = 1;                 //result is set at 1     by default
    while (pow > 0)             //while loop with pow set     to greater than 0
    {
        result = result * x;    //calculation for raising x by pow
        pow--;
    }
    return result;              //returning while loop results to function
}
```

Comment: Prototype and implementation signatures do not match.

Comment: To add to comment by @Eljay. In the declaration, you are using `int& result` while in the definition, you are using `int result`.

Comment: Why don't you just use the return value and not have a result parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you passing the result address? I'd suggest you to delete the result variable from the function arguments and the variable in the main scope, this would fix it.

```
int power(int pow,int x);
int main(){
    int pow,x;
    // Get the pow and number and the index, you wrote it

    cout << "Enter power: "; //prompt for integer in for power to be raised by 
    cin >> pow; //integer in 
    cout << "Enter value to be raised to power: "; 
    cin >> x;
    cout << Power(pow,x);
// If you want to store the result do
    int result = Power(pow,x);
}
int Power(int pow,int x){
   int result = 1; //result is set at 1 by default , you want to declare result here
while(pow > 0){
    result = result * x; 
    pow--; } 
return result;  }
```

The problem is that you have the definition that says `int &result` but you declare it as `int result`. The code above solves your problem and saves you from having to define the variable result and passing it to Power

Answer (score 0):

The declaration

```
int Power(/* in */int pow,/* in */int x,/* out */int &result);
```

Does not match the definition

```
int Power(/*in*/int pow,/*in*/int x,/*out*/int result);
```

Also, the definition has a `;` at the end that shouldn't be there. You could try changing it to:

```
int Power(/*in*/int pow,/*in*/int x,/*out*/int& result)
```

But I suggest you use `std::pow` instead.